# better way with Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

my HTML code is THE CODE IS REPEATED 16 times  :

```
<div class="headline_image">
<a ga-cat="slideshow-view" ga-action="view-1" href="mylink"><img src="http://dd4994.jpg" width="420" height="323" align="right" alt="my text "/></a>
</div>
```

I WANT TO GET all the imgs links and text also href what i did :

```
for ($x = 0; $x <=  15; $x++) {
$imglink = $html->find('div[class=headline_image] img', $x)->getAttribute('src');
$mytext = $html->find('div[class=headline_image] img', $x)->getAttribute('alt');
$postlink = $html->find('div[class=headline_image] a', $x)->getAttribute('href');
  echo '<br/>';
    echo $mytext;
     echo '<br/>';
    print_r($postlink);
    echo '<br/>';
    }
```

the code is slow any changes ?

Comment: you're scanning the entire dom each time for each find() call. Find the CONTAINER element of all these divs, and then you can base your scan from that point onwards.

Comment: , could you give me an example ?  sorry that's must be stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You slow down your code by using too much anonymous objects. It means you don't put the result of the function into a variable, rather just use it "on the go". This needs to run your function again and again slowing down your project.

Because you can use the function `find` to return an array, I advice you to do so before the for loop.

```
$imgarray = $html->find('div[class=headline_image] img', $x);
```

This way you run `$html->find` exactly once, and not sixteen times. In the for loop you can use it as an array and work with the results:  `$imgarray[$x]`. You make the same for `$anchorarray` and your code will speed up, you'll see.

Alternative solution is using PHP DOM `$childNodes` on the container in which this 16 item can be found (or the body element). This will return the sixteen `div` elements in which you can navigate by calling `$firstChild` for the `<a>` element and $firstChild again for the `<img>` element. Probably this is more secure in case you want to make changes to the website (like adding more content to the end etc.)

Comment: Thanks !! what do you think about the new code ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Daniel i changed the code to :

```
    $imgarray = $html->find('div[class=headline_image] img');
$linkarray = $html->find('div[class=headline_image] a');
for ($x = 0; $x <=  15; $x++) {

 echo $imgarray[$x]->getAttribute('src');
   echo '<br/>';
  echo $imgarray[$x]->getAttribute('alt');
     echo '<br/>';
   echo $linkarray[$x]->getAttribute('href');
  echo '<br/>';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the proper way to iterate looks like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div') as $div){
  echo $div;
}
```